# Does a Firestore batch.set() to a same document counts as one document write?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

If I do this in my code

```
 function setShards(batch, docRef, numShards) {
    batch.set(docRef, { numShards } , { merge: true });
 }

 const batch = firestore.batch();

 batch.set(docRef, {data});
 
 setShards(docRef, 10);

 batch.commit();
```

as you can see I am making a batch.set to the same document before doing the .commit(). So, will this count as one document write or as two document writes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`batch.set()` does not directly cost any document writes.  It is just queuing up a change locally before being sent to Firestore.  No billing occurs until you call `batch.commit()` successfully.  At that point, you will be charged as many document writes as are changes in the entire batch. So, if you only write one document in the batch, you will be charged on document write.

Comment: I may be misreading, but it's not 100% clear to me if batching 2 writes to a single document will be billed as 2 writes or as 1 write.

Comment: @gustavopch You are billed for the number of documents modified in the batch once it's committed, not for the number of modifications that you perform in the client. This is what the answer is saying.

Comment: @gustavopch It will be billed as 1 write, as eventually only 1 document was changes.